# There is a way to use "await" outside "async" on NodeJs with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

If I set this on **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    ...
}
```

I can use **await** outside **async**, but NodeJs doesn't work because NodeJs just understand **commonjs**.

There is a a way to do this on NodeJs?

Comment: Are you referring to [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)? CommonJS has nothing to do with whether this is supported or not. What versions of TypeScript and Node.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using node 14.3.0 and typescript 3.9.3